# Makefile will not expand dependencies

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

Using the following as an example makefile:

`CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lfoobar
SOURCES=main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello`

all: $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

$(OBJECTS):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$< always expands to nothing.

I've tried changing it to the following:

`CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello`

all: $(OBJECTS)  # or main.o foo.o bar.cpp
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

This tells me that there's no rule for main.o

Am I missing something here?  I see a lot of make files using these syntaxes and/or variables and dependencies.

Comment: `$<` stands for the list of prerequisites of `$(OBJECTS)`, you didn't give any. Just use the built-in rules like trojanfoe suggested.

Comment: The syntax for the second try seems right. Have you checked the output of make -rd and made sure main.cpp exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)  # or main.o foo.o bar.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
```

The rule to build each object file is built-in anyway, so there is no need to define it.

Comment: I directly copied and pasted yours into a new makefile and I'm still getting "No rule to make target `Main.o', needed by `hello'.  Stop."  I don't understand what's wrong with this...

Comment: Main.o?  Not main.o?  Looks like your file naming is broken!

Comment: That's..  odd.  I swear I copy and pasted it directly over..  I don't know how the capitalization got changed...  hrm..  I seem to be on the right track now though.